# problem with storing data from cache into useState in react native

Tags: react-native

```
    const [loggedInData, setLoggedInData] = useState([]);

    const getLoginFromCache = async() => {
        try{
            let logData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyDish:loginData');  
            let parsed = await JSON.parse(logData);
            console.log(parsed);
            setLoggedInData(parsed);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
   
    getLoginFromCache()

    console.log(loggedInData);
```

the result **console.log(loggedInData)** is always empty. whereas when i ***console.log(parsed)*** doesn't return empty

Answer (score 0):

Use redux persist for store data on cache and to state.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: i actually want to store it in a react UseState like so.  const [logData, setLogData] = useState([]);

Comment: Redux persist is much better than local asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

React set state is **async**, so `console.log(loggedInData);` will always print the initializtion state of `loggedInData`, in this case this state is an empty array

Try to wrap your `getLoginFromCache` function inside an `useEffect` like this:

```
const [loggedInData, setLoggedInData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const getLoginFromCache = async() => {
        try{
            let logData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyDish:loginData');  
            let parsed = await JSON.parse(logData);
            console.log(parsed);
            setLoggedInData(parsed);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    getLoginFromCache()
}, [])
```

and if you want tracking your `loggedInData` state, you can use another `useEffect` to log that one:

`useEffect(() => console.log(loggedInData),[loggedInData])`